# Why does my swift app crash whenever I go offline?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that requires the user to leave the app to connect to another device's wifi network. However, when I change to that wifi network and come back to the app, it seems as if Firebase or 'Google Data transport support' crashes the app saying 'there's no internet connection' when I already know there's no connection so how would I just ignore the error and carry on.

I used a breakpoint exception to find out where in code is causing the error and it's pointing me to this:

[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Nowhere in my code that I've written should cause that error as I'm not using firebase to query anything yet.

Comment: Log a bug with Google.  That is awful code. Throwing an exception simply because a network error occurred is a bad idea. Networks are unreliable. Networks can go offline. They should pass the error back to the caller and let the caller decide what to do. Crashing the application is not an appropriate response.

Comment: @Paulw11 that's what I thought. Is there any way around this since I don't want to wait for them to patch it? Like can I just disable that part? Could you also point me in the right direction to log this bug to Google?

Comment: Don't use Firebase? Fork their code and change it yourself? Although it doesn't look like this is a trivial thing to fix since that function doesn't even accept a completion handler. I don't know where you would log the bug - there is probably a GitHub repo for this framework, but I have never used firebase.

Comment: You could try opening an issue here - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues

Comment: @Paulw11 okay thanks for the advice, I'll have to try and ask on the firebase Github or something. Just needed confirmation that it was google's bug and not mine.

Comment: @Paulw11 well I'm guessing it's firebase since it says 'GDTCCT' in the console?

Comment: [this](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3530) is the same issue. They have closed it, but I am not sure why since I think this is pretty awful code. `NSAssert` should only be used when there is no hope of recovery

Comment: @Paulw11 Yep, I've opened a new one and linked here.

Comment: The issue has been patched and new versions of the libraries released. You can pod update to get the new versions. NSAsserts are meant to catch potential issues in a development environment, and I was perhaps a bit too overzealous with them. NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS is defined by default in release builds (though you can undefine it), and this wasn't really an issue in shipped apps or binary distributions of Firebase. Either way, I replaced the asserts with console logging statements for now. In the future, we'll get these libraries to better adhere to log levels specified in Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `pod update` to pick up the fix that released today.

Details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3530

Comment: My app still crash when device disconnected from cellular network. pod updated to latest Firebase version. EDIT: it crashes not exactly then going offline, app crashes when reconnected.